# ios backup using http

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, http, ios5

I've spent hours now looking for an answer to this question and I can't seem to find it anywhere.

Are there any tutorials or sample code that help with setting up an http connection so that a user can use the browser to save the application coredata sqlite file to the desktop and/or send a previous sqlite backup to the app?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Cocoa HTTP Server](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaHTTPServer). I have used it before, and it works great.

It has:

- Built in support for bonjour broadcasting IPv4 and IPv6 support
- Asynchronous networking using GCD and standard sockets
- Password protection support
- SSL/TLS encryption support
- Extremely FAST and memory efficient
- Extremely scalable (built entirely upon GCD)
- Heavily commented code
- Very easily extensible WebDAV is supported too!

Comment: Thanks, been reading a bit about it and seems like a dev called Nonnus back in 2008 wrote a good example of what I'm looking for iPhoneHTTPServer which uses cocoaHTTPserver and I see a lot of new apps using that exact same example. Looked for a new version of his code but with no luck so far... anyone has a bookmark somewhere to an updated version?

Comment: Nah that's not it, what I'm looking for is defenetly what was done in 2008 by Nonnus as iPhoneHTTPServer but I can't seem to find any recent version or anything similar which is weird because I see this being used in loads of apps.